# What does "blade" mean exactly in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I saw this sentence in an [online article](https://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/a19260/i-took-a-road-trip-in-a-lamborghini-supercar/).

> Like its predecessors—the Countach, Diablo, and Murciélago—the Aventador SV is an impossibly wide, ridiculously low-slung **blade** of a car, with doors that scissor skyward and a huge V-12 behind the seats.

I know **blade** means a dashing man, but not sure it applies here. None of the word's definitions appear to fit here. What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my guess. Blade doesn't have special meaning here. The car is being compared to a blade, like a sword blade. Blades can be "wide" or thin, and "low-slung" makes be think of a sword that's hung (or *slung*) on one's side so that it's low to the ground. I assume the car also rides low to the ground. I think the metaphor continues by saying that the doors "scissor" towards the sky. This also references the name "scissor doors". And the body is designed to cut (= move quickly) through the air, like a blade.

There's also a possible *bullfighting* reference, as apparently Lamborghinis are named after famous fighting bulls. From Wikipedia

> The [Lamborghini Aventador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Aventador) is a mid-engined sports car produced by the Italian automotive manufacturer Lamborghini. In keeping with Lamborghini tradition, the Aventador is named after a fighting bull. Aventador (pronounced [aβentaˈðoɾ]) earned the Trofeo de la Peña La Madroñera for its courage in the arena in Zaragoza, Spain, in 1993.

Comment: A "blade-like" car will "cut" through the air in a way that improves speed -- and, not incidentally, looks extremely *cool*.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `{noun1} of a {noun2}` is a form of metaphorical comparison, where noun2 is being called a noun1.

> He was a lion of a man.
>
> It was a smokestack of a hat.

So the car is being likened to a blade (knife, sword, fan, axe, adze) -- something sleek  and aerodynamic.  It has very little ground clearance and has itself little height, like a blade lying with its broad side parallel to the ground.

Answer (score 1):

They probably mean the front lower part of the car, which means there's almost no gap between the ground and the bottom of the car.